# Cakephp save doesnt save assosiated model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables `Users` and `Clients`

Users table struckture looks like this:

```
  id (primary)
  username(varchar)
password, client_id
```

Now my client table looks like this:

```
user_id, client_id(primary), is_new
```

The relation between these are defined as follow:

```
    class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Client' =>array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'dependent' => true,
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        )
    );
}


    class Client extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Client';
    public $primaryKey = 'client_id';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'dependent' => true,
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Now in my userscontroller i have the following save action:

```
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = null;
        $client_id = null;
        if ($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 1) {
            $client_id = 2;

        } elseif ($this->request->data['User']['group_id'] == 2) {
            $client_id = $this->request->data['User']['Client id'];
        }
        $data = array('User' => array(
            'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
            'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password'],
            'group_id' => $this->request->data['User']['group_id'],
            'client_id' => $client_id),
        'Client' => array('client_id' => $client_id)
        );

        if ($this->User->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
}
```

When i save a new entity is added to the users table with the correct client_id but nothing has been added into clients table.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Note that i have tried to change the function to `saveAll();`

**Update**

If i do the following:

```
        $data = array( 'User' => array( 'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
                'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password'],
                'group_id' => $this->request->data['User']['group_id'],
                'client_id' => $client_id ),
                'Client' => array('client_id' => $client_id) );
            if ($this->User->Client->saveAll($data)) {
}
```

Aka use `$this->User->Client->saveAll` instead of `$this->User->saveAll()`

Everything works fine..

Now this is good but is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: why are you not using `$this->User->save<whatever>($this->request->data)`, instead of effectively copying it to another variable ? From the look of the code you'd be better off putting that code in a model function so that controller code is simply `$this->User->register($this->request->data);` - Fat models, thin controllers

Comment: @AD7six the only reason im doing this is because there is only 1 case as to where i have to hardcode my client_id (it has something to do with the access of my program) this could be converted to the model i do agree though

Comment: `$this->request->data['Client']['client_id'] = $foo` would do that - it looks like it's only necessary to do that sometimes though, would be 2 lines of code instead of ~14

Comment: it will work for you as well

Comment: @AD7six actually if i did that instead of the above update it failed.

Comment: @Marc I'm saying don't create another variable copying keys from `request->data` instead just manipulate `request->data` and pass it to the model method - if it doesn't work (in a different way), you aren't doing that =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$this->User->saveAssociated($data)` instead of `$this->User->save($data)`

**Update**

Just set the data for client without field **id** as like below inorder to save the data while saving of user.

```
$data = array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'], 
        'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password']
    ), 
    'Client' => array(
        'field1' => 'field1value',
        'field2' => 'field2value',
        'field3' => 'field3value'
    )
);
```

Comment: if i do this i get 2013-09-19 11:43:52 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' meaning it couldnt find my client_id

Comment: Just try like this, may work

`$data = array(
 'User' => array(
        'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
        'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password'],
        'group_id' => $this->request->data['User']['group_id'],
        'client_id' => $client_id
    ),
    'Client' => array()
);`

Comment: That got rid of the sql error but did not insert anything into the clients table (aka we are back to the begining)

Comment: Just try to put something into your client as like this.

`$data = array(
 'User' => array(
        'username' => $this->request->data['User']['username'],
        'password' => $this->request->data['User']['password'],
        'group_id' => $this->request->data['User']['group_id'],
        'client_id' => $client_id
    ),
    'Client' =>  array(
        array('body' => 'Comment 1', 'user_id' => 1),
        array('body' => 'Save a new user as well', 'User' => array('first' => 'mad', 'last' => 'coder')),
    )
);`

Comment: Even if it is not working then definitely it's the problem of your setting of primary key i.e. `client_id`

Comment: your relationship between the table is very confusing. Why do you need client_id on both table ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari one is a foreign key (conventionally named) and the other is the primary key (not conventionally named) - it's quite normal (except the name `clients.id` -> `clients.client_id`).

Comment: I just gave an example for OP's understanding @MoyedAnsari

Answer (score 1):

Yes these both are same, only difference between them is that  saveAssoicated is used when you need to save associated models at once whereas saveAll is wrapper of saveAssociated,

You can use **saveAssociated**

> $this->User->saveAssociated($data)

as well as **saveAll()**

> $this->User->saveAll($data)

Thanks