# CakePHP saving HABTM data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, cakephp

I have 2 models, `Client` and `Security`. They are associated with a HATBTM relationship.
I have made a join table called `clients_securities`. So a `Client` can have many securities and a `Security` can belong to many `Client`s.

[image]

Here are my relationship definitions:

```
 //Client Model:
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Security' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Security',
            'joinTable' => 'clients_securities',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'security_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
);

 //Security Model:
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Client' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'clients_securities',
            'foreignKey' => 'security_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'client_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
);
```

I then made an edit action in my clients controller and did this:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }

        $client = $this->Client->findById($id);
        if (!$client) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid client'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $this->Client->id = $id;
            if ($this->Client->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Client has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $id));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update client.'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $client;
            $this->set('securities', $this->Client->Security->find('list'));
        }
    }
```

In my edit view I build the form using the HtmlHelper, adding the client table fields and generating the multiple select with:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Client'); //start the form for the client model
echo $this->Form->input('Security'); //generates a multi-select popuplated with securities
```

In addition I also have normal direct form inputs for the `Client` in the same form. e.g.

```
echo $this->Form->input('name'); //Input for the client name
echo $this->Form->input('currency'); //Input for the client currency
...
```

All these inputs get generated and populated with the correct values when the form is rendered but only the direct Client data is saved, not the HABTM data from the multi-select.

When I submit the form the `clients_securities` table is not populated with the join IDs.

What do I need to do to save it correctly and have then have the saved securities be pre-selected when I reload the "edit" view.

---

Edit: To clarify things, here is a `pr()` of `$this->request->data`. 
(The values ("ALLCMCT LX Equity") are the correct foreign keys for the `securities` table):

```
Array
(
    [Client] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1212
            [name] => Example Client
            [currency] => GBP
            [partner] => 
            [risk_category_id] => 4
            [client_code_id] => 1
            [min_cash_balance] => 0
            [active] => 1
            [model] => 0
            [institutional] => 0
            [non_uk_situs] => 0
            [reporting_status] => 0 
        )

    [Security] => Array
        (
            [Security] => Array
                (
                    [0] => .1muslib3 index
                    [1] => .eurib3 index
                    [2] => .ukcpi2 index
                )

        )

)
```

So essentially, say my client id was 12345, Cake should insert 2 records in the `clients_securities` table like so:

```
id | client_id | security_id
----------------------------
1  | 12345     | ALLCMCT LX Equity
2  | 12345     | APMKNTD LX Equity
```

If I manually add some join records into `clients_securities`, when I go to edit a client the securities in the multi-select come up correctly pre-selected showing that the data is being read from the join table. When I save the form it actually removes the join records but does not save new ones.

Additional note: **My security IDs are stored as CHAR(36)** if that has any effect. This is not an auto-increment field, it contains the ticker of the security and each is unique.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18891807/1239506

Comment: I've read all the related questions I can find without success.

Comment: It should work the way you did. Anyway, did you try `'unique' => 'keepExisting'`, instead? Also, I don't think that the ID format is an issue, but just to be sure did you try with a INT fake id? Lastly: could you please post a complete `pr($this->request->data)` (without sensitive data, of course)

Comment: Question amended to include the entire `$this-request->data`. I think I want to keep the `unique` as true as I want the old links to be removed before the new ones are inserted.

Comment: I have a similar situation in one project of mine but I have numeric ids. I tried changing id to char(30) and it stopped working. If I mix numeric and char values it only saves numeric!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the format of the `security_id` and `Security.id`: char is unsupported.

I found this [ticket](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3091-habtm-automagic-save-not-respecting-non-uuid-id-values) (but I don't find any reference in the documentation)

you must create another column with a numeric `id` to use in the HABTM association

Comment: If I change my column type to CHAR(36) would this solve it? Edit: no, it does not.

Comment: Might it work if I rework my relationships into `hasMany` and `belongsTo` ones? How would I do this?

Comment: In my opinion the best way is to use a numeric id and rename the current id into something like 'name' or 'alfanumeric_identifier'. If you can't do this then you can save manually the items in the `clients_securities` table putting the `$this->request->data['Security']['Security']` array in a foreach cicle. i.e. `$this->Client->ClientsSecurity->save(array('client_id' => $client_id, 'security_id' => $security_id));`. Just remember to delete old relationships first

Comment: SOLVED! At last. You are absolutely correct. Adding an integer primary key column to my securities table now makes it work. Many thanks, have a bounty

Answer (score 1):

modify your form input like so:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Security.Security');
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
Model::saveAssociated(array $data = null, array $options = array());

or

Model::saveAll(array $data = null, array $options = array());
?>
```

For more info please visit: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: Please let me know if any trubble in above code. glad to help you :)

Comment: I tried changing `save` to `saveAll` but no luck. It doesn't look as if the data in the multiple select is being posted with the other data.

Comment: If I manually add a join record to the database it populates and preselects the securities correctly. It just won't save.

Comment: In fact, when I save it actually deletes the current join records without saving new ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try...

You forgot $this->Client->read(); after $this->Client->id = $id; in the edit() function (the internal of $this->Client are not initialized, so no client_id is present at the moment when save is done). The call "findById" will return only an array, but won't read the data to the object $this->Client.

Just a good educated guess..

Comment: Sorry, no change with this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm worng but I guess you forgot to create a hidden input with the Client id in your view

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Client.id');
```

Comment: The form is already associated with `Client` and there is an input for client id in it. Full request data is now in the question

Answer (score 0):

Its not populating mediater table because After populating both models It does not have their id to populate mediater table. So user beforeSave and afterSave function which will populate your mediator table. Add beforesave function in Client model

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        parent::beforeSave($options = array());
            foreach (array_keys($this->hasAndBelongsToMany) as $model):
                if(isset($this->data[$this->alias][$model])):
                    $this->data[$model][$model] = $this->data[$this->alias][$model];
                    unset($this->data[$this->alias][$model]);
                endif;
            endforeach;
        return true;
    }
```

And in Security user AfterSave function,

```
public $securityIdArray = array();

public function afterSave($created) {
        if($created) {
            $this->securityIdArray[] = $this->getInsertID();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

First save security and use $securityIdArray to get id of security after $this->Model->save in your controller.

```
$this->Security->securityIdArray[] = $void['Security']['id'];
```

And yah As @Arilia said Modify you forum input field

```
echo $this->Form->input('Security.Security');
```

and don't make saperate forms for both models

Comment: Re your last point, which form model would the `Security.Security` field belong to? The purpose is to assign 1 or more securities to a client, which is analogous to assigning tags to a post. Surely the Client form is correct.

Comment: Also, the `Securities` model is never, and doesn't need to be populated, only the join table. There are already securities in the table. The purpose is to choose some and have them "belongTo" the client.