# Cant save data in DB using save() function provided by cake php

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am quite new to cakephp.

I created a company and a user model and a register controller. A user registers one company and the company can have a lot of users.

The issue i having is that i can insert a new company  by using:

```
$this->query("INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES('".$name."');");
```

This query is used within the company model which inserts the company name in the companies table and auto generates the id primary key but this method is open for sql injection and goes against cake php conventions.

I tried another method where i assigned the company name to the name parameter of the company model and execute the save() function.

```
$this->name = $name; 
$this->save();
```

but this way the company name is not being inserted in the database. after running debug all i get is BEGIN and ROLLBACK functions.

I dumped the table and schema from within the model too verify if there is connection issues but there are none.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you should user proper naming convention of cakephp such as company information is always saved from Company Model

Comment: you should follow this link http://cakephpcheatsheet.com/ or http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: Since you are new to Cakephp, do yourself a **huge** favor, read about and use Cakephp's code generation ability: [bake functionality](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html). _(That is for v2.x, v.3 also has this capability)._ Once Cakephp builds out the initial models, views and controllers you can begin to understand how the code works that is relevant to your data model.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not experienced in CakePHP, but this is what I would be doing.

Following CakePHP conventions would have you do the following:

- Create models Company and User(CakePHProot/app/model/Company.php;User.php).
- Create controllers (CakePHProot/app/controller/CompaniesController.php;UsersController.php).
- Create the following tables Companies and User.
- Associate the models.
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html
- Create createCompany function in CompanyController.Delete the registerController.

  ```
  public function createCompany() {
          if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
              $this -> Company -> create();
              if ($this -> Company -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
                  $this -> Session -> setFlash(('Your company has been created.'));
                  return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
              }
              $this -> Session -> setFlash(('Unable to create your company.'));
          }
      }
  //You can add the company_founder_id in the view if such a field exists.
  ```

  This might be relevant: [CakePHP saving HABTM data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893392/cakephp-saving-habtm-data?rq=1)